# Anyway to reduce bundle size of App in my angular webpack app?

Tags: angular, webpack, bundle

I'm newer to this area and following up after getting some more information, Am I wrong in understanding this... but  it looks like my main is loading along with platform-browser-dynamic which bootstraps my App-Module.

Is there anyway to bring these bundles down or optimize them that I can look into?

Currently using webpack with Angular 6.

[image: Foam Tree App Bundle]

Comment: it seems you are building your app with AOT mode disabled. because of this compiler is carried over to the fronted and increases the bundle size. in your case it is not the major part, so I wouldn't care about that much. Instead enabling the AOT will greatly reduce the CPU consumption on the page start time, and this point IMO affects the page load time much more than bundle size improvements

Comment: `jQuery` is a good candidate to remove, you should not use it in an angular app. EDIT: also, what are those `json`s? Can't those be lazy loaded?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I already am Lazy loading them,  before jquery was in my vendor bundle and the json is actually animation data for gsap. I guess they can be lazy loaded @AlexBrio

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in a solid direction if you come across any relevant articles please share them in this thread I would appreciate it!